# Joda-time MissingResourceException

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, jodatime

I'm getting a

`java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name org.joda.time.format.messages, locale en`

in the following piece of code;

```
    DateTime start = new DateTime();
    DateTime end = new DateTime(2017, 3, 26, 12, 0, 0, 0);
    Interval interval = new Interval(start, end);


    Period period = interval.toPeriod();

    // This line is causing the exception.
    System.out.println(PeriodFormat.getDefault().print(period));
```

Relevant part of the stack trace:

```
Caused by: java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name org.joda.time.format.messages, locale en
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.throwMissingResourceException(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_65]
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundleImpl(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_65]
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_65]
    at org.joda.time.format.PeriodFormat.buildWordBased(PeriodFormat.java:217) ~[?:?]
    at org.joda.time.format.PeriodFormat.wordBased(PeriodFormat.java:205) ~[?:?]
    at org.joda.time.format.PeriodFormat.getDefault(PeriodFormat.java:73) ~[?:?]
```

I'm using Joda Time 2.9.2 and Intellij IDEA 15.0.1 with mainly Maven

[The module](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DZ21o.png)

Comment: Hmm, the exception does not occur in a plain new java command line project.

Comment: Well, strange, I restarted the server it was running on and it worked..

Answer (score 0):

I think it is fixed now.. Yesterday it appeared to happen after reloading the bukkit/spigot (Minecraft) server this plugin was running on. It would work fine when restarting the server, but a reload would break it. But today it just all seems to work fine. Strange, no idea what caused it.

EDIT:
It appears a bukkit server just doesn't handle resource bundles when reloading well at all. One reload just breaks everything wich uses resource bundles.

Comment: Ok and now it broke again, really strange. I think this is a issue with how spigot/bukkit handles plugins.